# How to add 'Window Manager\Window Manager Group' to 'increase scheduling priority'

Tags: windows-10, group-policy

As I was having issues with black flashes when writing on my Windows 10 convertible, I found that adding 'Window Manager\Window Manager Group' to 'increase scheduling priority' in the local policies should solve the problem.
But it was already added and I accidently removed it, if I try to add it back (in the policy editor `gpedit.msc`), it just says "The object cannot be found".

Comment: Kindly check if this article form Microsoft can help you: [Increase scheduling priority](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/increase-scheduling-priority)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem can be solved by adding `*S-1-5-90-0` to `SeIncreaseBasePriorityPrivilege`

- right-click security settings and export settings to a file
- open the file, search for `SeIncreaseBasePriorityPrivilege` and append `*S-1-5-90-0` (if there are previous entries, use a comma)
- save the file, right-click security settings again, and import the modified file

Comment: This is fantastic. I used this method (I created a specific inf file) to fix an issue plaguing me for  a number of weeks where ink drawing didn't work properly (in applications like Snip & Sketch, Onenote, Visio and cause drawing to not follow the cursor and to blank the screen. This issue was described by someone here - https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/snip-sketch-screen-flickering-when-drawing/17d951d1-ec06-43fc-b8cb-f43129d820bc with a fix here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/increase-scheduling-priority